# Scroll animation not work in mac book retina

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, retina-display

The animation for the menu bar and image banner not work in mac book retina display. But it work in normal display without retina. I'm add trigger console but not shown anything when scroll.

Here is the web link : http://sarichem.com/html

Here is the code:

```js
$(window).ready(function() {

  var pageWidth = $(window).width();

  if (pageWidth > 1281) {
    $(window).on('scroll',function() {
      var amount = $(window).scrollTop();
      var amount2 = 1-(amount/10000);
      console.log(amount2);

      $(".slideanimate").css({"-webkit-transform": 'scale(' + amount2 + ')', "-moz-transform": 'scale(' + amount2 + ')', "transition": "all 0.3s"});

      if($(window).scrollTop() > 700) {
      $(".navhome1").css({"-webkit-opacity": "0", "-moz-opacity": "0", "opacity": "0"});
      } else {
        $(".navhome1").css({"-webkit-opacity": "1", "-moz-opacity": "1", "opacity": "1"});
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Case resolved.

I'm adding detection for desktop. Here is the full code:

```js
$(window).ready(function() {

  var pageWidth = $(window).width();
  var istablet = (/ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
  var isDesktop = (function() {
    return !('ontouchstart' in window) // works on most browsers 
    || !('onmsgesturechange' in window); // works on ie10
  })();
  window.isDesktop = isDesktop;

  if (isDesktop || istablet) {
     $(window).on('scroll',function() {
      var amount = $(window).scrollTop();
      var amount2 = 1-(amount/10000);
      console.log(amount2);

      $(".slideanimate").css({"-webkit-transform": 'scale(' + amount2 + ')', "-moz-transform": 'scale(' + amount2 + ')', "transition": "all 0.3s"});

      if(amount > 700) {
      $(".navhome1").css({"-webkit-opacity": "0", "-moz-opacity": "0", "opacity": "0"});
      } else {
        $(".navhome1").css({"-webkit-opacity": "1", "-moz-opacity": "1", "opacity": "1"});
      }
    });
  };
});
```